# how to add subgroup sum as labels to histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I want add sum by group to my histogram as label.
I have data as following:

```
group total
a       2
a       2
b       4
b       4
c       2
c       9
c       9
```

my r code is

```
size<-df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  summarise(total=sum(total))

df%>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(group,desc(total))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=group, y=total)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=1, width=.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Active Leisure Type") +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(y=size,label=size))
```

it is not working. I am just wondering if there any fix will be done in `geom_text` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a new column for labels with `sum` of `total` in each group. Replace all the values to empty except the last one so that only one value is printed for each bar.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(group,desc(total))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(new_total=sum(total), 
         new_total = replace(new_total, -n(), '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=group, y=total)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=1, width=.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Active Leisure Type") +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=new_total), size = 5, hjust = -0.5, 
            vjust = 1, position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: could you explain little bit  "new_total = replace(new_total, -n(), ''))"? thank you.

Comment: In `new_total` we keep the total value for only the last row in each `group`. Rest of them are turned as empty value. `n()` gives number of rows in each group. So `-n()` means except last row in the group turn them  to empty values